# What is the potential security risk of including the db password in the web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, web

The Entity data Model wizard says :

This connection string appears to contain sensitive data (for example, a password) that is required to 
connect to the database. Storing sensitive data in the connection string can be a security risk. Do you want 
to include this sensitive data in the connection string?

I have included the db password in many live projects, How risky is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to how secure is your domain and IIS on your web server? IIS and web.config is at the root of your web application. If you have problems with domain security and people being able to access your inetpub or wwwroot directories and their children, then your website is always at risk. If you are using a third party provider such as go daddy or 1 and 1, they are relatively secure.

If you are hosting it yourself, you want to limit access, especially directory listing privileges. You want to mitigate permissions as much as possible. Also with your SQL Account you use for your web applications, limit database privileges and mitigate access as much as possible. Also do not use generic accounts for access, and have each web app with their own account. In a domain, you want to make sure you take the necessary precautions in your DMZ to help secure that web server if it sits on the edge of your network.

Internal threats are more prevalent than external threats. Those already on your domain with elevated privileges may already have access to your root of your web application without you even knowing it! Keep an eye on your delegate accounts, too that IIS uses for web apps and web services.

Answer (score 3):

It is all about minimizing your risk. Lets say a attacker found a way of getting a copy of the code from the server but not a way to execute code on the server:

- If you stored the username and password in the code the attacker now has direct access to your database with the same privileges as your code.
- If you used integrated authentication the attacker still does not have any way to get data from your database as he can not impersonate the user to perform integrated authentication.
- If you use proper [IIS encrption](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/304638/Encrypt-or-Decrypt-Connection-Strings-in-web-confi) you must be able to execute code on the server itself (the encryption key is tied to the server not the code) to be able to get the username and password. So the attacker still would not have access to the database.

Comment: But you don't want to minimize risk to zero because that costs more money than it saves. There's an optimal point which is never zero.

Comment: @usr - The only zero risk is to unplug the server, and melt it down.  Beyond that, there is always some risk.  Connect it to the net, there is risk.  So your comment is largely pointless.

Comment: @usr good point! It's always important to do cost benefit analysis. To quote [FightClub](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Fight_Club_%28film%29) "*... should we initiate a recall? Take the number of vehicles in the field, A, multiply by the probable rate of failure, B, multiply by the average out-of-court settlement, C. A times B times C equals X. If X is less than the cost of a recall, we don't do one.*"

Comment: I like the Fight Club metaphor and agree 100%. IS it worth your time and money to mitigate risk to 0. We all take calculated risks when we program our apps, and put them externally available, then we mitigate to the point where it's manageable and management is appeased.

Answer (score 3):

Risk is something only you can evaluate.  Is it a test server in your bedroom that is not connected to the internet?  Not much risk.  Is it an internal company server for a small company without any real sensitive information?  Maybe not much risk.

Is it connected to the internet?  It's risky.  It's always risky if you're connected to the internet.  Why?  Because the internet is not a safe place.  It doesn't matter how big or small you are, you're a target.  There are automated bots that roam the net looking for vulnerable systems and automatically taking them over.  Then, they infect the systems with Malware to spread to your users.  Or they sell your credentials to other hackers so they can use your servers for command and control centers for spam networks.  Or any number of other situations.

If you're on the internet, you are at risk.  Period.  So always take security seriously.

Answer (score 2):

You should encrypt the connection string using **[aspnet_regiis](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/304638/Encrypt-or-Decrypt-Connection-Strings-in-web-confi)** Take a look at this link too ([How To Encrypt web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986855.aspx)), for some useful information.

With regards to other aspects of the web application, you need to make sure you are setting the **least privileges possible**, making sure you research all web application vulnerabilities and how to protect against these.

Comment: This is not a risk assessment.

Comment: Not only that, but it really doesn't make anything more secure.  If the server can decode it, so can an attacker on the server.

Comment: Agreed, but if the password was in plain text, then even users with access to the server would be able to see the password - doesn't need to be an attacker.

Comment: @christiandev - while true, it's better to use integrated security.  Unless of course you're on a hosting provide and don't have a domain, in which case you're boned either way.

Comment: @MystereMan, I agree, but my point is purely to secure anything sensitive.  I have worked on projects internally with plain text passwords.  I could easily have jumped onto their DB server, and had elevated rights.

Answer (score 2):

Replace user name and password with **Integrated Security** in the Connection string.
Ensure that the process using the connection executes with a user that has been registered on the SQL server with (*just enough*) privilegies to perform its tasks. This should minimize the risk of your system being compromised.